# TFS2010 / VS2010 - Error when edit a Build Definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs, build-definition

I'm using VS2010 and TFS2010, unfortunately, my custom activity is not compiled, when I queue my Build Definition. Probably that happens because I get this error when I open/edit the Buil Definition, I can see this in the Output :

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 1 errors and 0 warnings loading custom activities and services.
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Moreover, when I queue the Build Definition I don't have any error, my custom activity is skipped.
All my assemblies are with the version 10, so this mistake is strange for me.

I edited the XAML file such as this article : https://pragmaticpattern.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/opening-a-tfs-2010-build-process-template-in-visual-studio-2012-update/, but nothing happens.

Thank you, enjoy TFS :)

Comment: What's the detail build log? Can you share the project and build process template file on the OneDrive?

Comment: This is the link for the OneDrive containing the project with the XAML file, and the build log. https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArhrM04sz7wtbpCVTLoXmPCjyW0

Comment: Based on the log file the CopyActivityAppTest already executed, what do mean the custom activity is skipped? Do you mean the directory isn't created? Try to change the build service account to your account and try again.